# Friction and internal energy of an irreversible adiabatic compression of ideal gas

Tags: friction

Hi i have read that the friction between the piston and the cylinder wall increases the temperature and, thus, the internal energy of the ideal gas. But how can the dissipated energy due to firction appear in the gas. The surface is only “heated“ when rhe piston moved by and therefore the heated wall has no contact to the gas anymore.

Comment: There is also a small amount of friction between the gas and the wall, as well as internal friction (viscosity) to the gas itself.

Comment: It all depends on the details of the device

Comment: I can't visualize how the gas can be prevented from contacting the heated wall. As Wolfram johnny points out, you need to provide more detail in order for us to provide a suitable answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunateley, I do not have further details about the device.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the bulk material, perhaps metals, of the cylinder conducts heat through metal atom-metal atom collisions.  This kinetic energy will propagate through the cylinder, as well as the inner surface of the piston.